# How to insert multiple PDF files into database using SSMS

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a folder on my PC that contains nearly 300000 pdf files (~25GB). By using a SQL script, I want to insert all those pdf files into my database, including filename and the PDF file itself.

I have followed many tutorials or articles around there but all of them require the filename to be defined one-by-one for each file.
[Upload files article](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3632741/Upload-multiple-files-to-VarBinary-column-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm/).

I want to have a stored procedure like this one:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Importfiles] (

    @FolderPath NVARCHAR (1000)

   )
AS
BEGIN
         DECLARE @tsql NVARCHAR (2000);
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   SET @tsql = 'insert into dokumentet ( name, files) ' +
               ' SELECT  ' + // I would like to select all files here (including their file name)
               'FROM Openrowset( Bulk ' + '''' + @FolderPath + '''' + ', Single_Blob) as pdf'
   EXEC (@tsql)
   SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

My database table schema, and source folder is like this:

[image: Destination table][image]
*Name* is the file name, *Files* is the pdf file.

They should look like this on the database table:
[image]

Once again my goal is to create a SQL script to take the file and its name automatically, and insert them in the table. But I'm having difficulties.

Comment: sqlserver: create a list of your files by whatever means, f.e.:  `dir /b/j > file.csv` and import that into your db (sql server import tools in ssms f.e.) into a table that you then can join to your `insert into - select`-statement

Comment: MS SQL @PatrickArtner